# Python and beautifulsoup - How to select only a specific slection of a class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
mainBody = urlsoup.find_all(style_="display: none;")
mainBody = urlsoup.find_all(style_="display: none;"[0])
```

If there are two of the same styles or classes, how do I select the 1st or 2nd?
How could I get the second line of code to work allowing me to select one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting the `[0]` to an incorrect place, replace:

```
mainBody = urlsoup.find_all(style_="display: none;"[0])
```

with:

```
mainBody = urlsoup.find_all(style_="display: none;")[0]
```

Comment: Dude you're awesome! It worked and I even added `.text` at the end and now I'm able to scrape the data I want! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The `find_all` method returns a list.

```
mainBody = urlsoup.find_all(style_="display: none;")
```

Then you can access the elements as in a standard list:

```
first = mainBody[0]
second = mainBody[1]
```

Comment: Amazing and thanks to you also because that just opened my eyes on how to add each list element to a different element specific to what I want to call it! You rock!